# If $f$ is continuous on $[1,8]$ and some values of $f$ are given, which of the following statement concerning the existence of solutions must be true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

[image] I have graphed this function, and it seems to be a parabola like figure. However, I am not sure what I am supposed to do. Am i supposed to construct the function? Or am I missing the point here? A small hint to guide me in the right direction would be appreciated! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function need not be a parabola.

We know that the function is continuous, try to use **intermediate value theorem** to make conclusion. For example, we know that $f(x)=0$ must has a solution in $[1,5]$ since $f(1)=-2$ and $f(5)=10$. and we have $-2 \le 0 \le 10$.

Also, construct counter examples of functions to show that some of them need not be true.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Will try to solve using the theorem

Answer (score 3):

No, you are not supposed to construct the function.(That's impossible). Since you know that $f$ is continuous my hint is to use Bolzano's Theorem.

Comment: [Bolzano's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) is a special case of the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: Sure. Although there is some sort of equivalency between the two.(I also think that historically Bolzano's was proved first and used to obtain the generalization that is the IVT). Anyways, since that's kind of a beginner in analysis question, isn't Bolzano's more appropriate for a hint? First you learn the special case, then you learn general one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this hint is sufficiently small but consider the following problem:

Is it possible to construct a continuous function f for which f(0)=0, f(1)=1, but for which $|\{x \mid x \in [0,1], f(x)=1/2\}|=0$?

There is a theorem which can guide your thinking. The above problem should guide you toward it.

(The theorem I allude to is the IVT. Revealing this amounts to giving away the solution, but it seems that the cat is out of the bag)